# knockout observable declaration ways

Tags: knockout.js

I saw the obeservable is declare as below

```
viewModel = ko.observable({

        currentUser: ko.observable({
        userInfo: ko.observable()
    })
})
```

here Observable is declared like ko.observable({ }).What is mean by it.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces in JavaScript is an object declaration allowing you to create an object that contains multiple properties of various types.

Initializing `ko.observable` with an open and closed curly brace `ko.observable({})` is initializing the observable with an empty object. The code you listed above will create an observable object that keeps track of the changes of that object.